# jQuery .bind binded function not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, asp-classic

I've been searching for a solution for a while now but I can't still get my code get to work.

I'm trying to bind 'input' event. Here's what I have so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtRTMUserID').bind('keyup', function () {
        var inputValue = $('#txtRTMUserID').val();
        inputValue = inputValue.replace(/-/g, "");
        var outputVal = "";
        var inputLength = inputValue.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < inputLength; i++) {

            outputVal += inputValue.charAt(i);

            if (i == 7) {
                outputVal += "-";
            }
            if (i == 11) {
                outputVal += "-";
            }
            if (i == 15) {
                outputVal += "-";
            }
            if (i == 19) {
                outputVal += "-";
            }
        }
        $('#txtRTMUserID').val(outputVal);
    });
});
```

Here's my textbox control:

```
<input type="text" id="txtUserID" value = "@ConsumerID"  tabindex="20" style="width: 250px;" maxLength="36"/>
```

> **UPDATE:**
>
> I finally got it working on paste event. See my updated script above.
>   One problem though, when I paste a valid GUID, then press the right
>   arrow (to make corrections) it immediately brings me back to the end
>   of the text in the textbox. I must enable the user to make
>   corrections.

Comment: Your selector is wrong. An ID selector requires `#`.

Comment: like $('#txtUserID)' ?

Comment: What behavior do you want with "input" ivent. Do you want to act as "onClick" or "onChange"?

Comment: Yes, that's how you select by ID.

Comment: @Habibillah: OP probably wants the "oninput" behavior with the "input" event.

Comment: Habibillah - I want to catch the 'Paste' event

Comment: @Crazy Train - I added the # but it still doesn't work for me. :(

Comment: @Agent X44: It could be a browser issue, sometimes javascript and IE don't play well.

Comment: @Agent X44: Also, to get the value from an element you can use JQuery ie. $("#txtUserID").val();

Comment: @Agent X44: You should also use the above to set the value ie. $("#txtUserID").val(outputVal);

Comment: @uofc: Heh, little hissy fit from you just means nothing. Agent X44: Don't use `$("#txtUserID").val();` to get/set the value. It's a common beginner mistake. You already have a reference to the element, so use `$(this).val()` if you want to use jQuery. But you really don't need jQuery methods here either. Just use `var foo = this.value;` and `this.value = "new value"`. It's *much* faster.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: Hahahahahaha beginner mistake? HAHAHAHAHAHA. You think you're a pro because you used "this" instead of the tag id? HAHAHAHAHAH Please proceed to kill yourself.

Comment: @uofc: Yes, this is a common beginner mistake. There's no need to perform DOM selection for an element that is directly available.

Comment: @CrazyTrain thanks for that pointer. I'll take note of that. Either way it works the same, thanks guys. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. don't use `input` event, it's not supported in many browsers, use `keyup` instead, it works on paste also
2. don't mix jQuery with pure JS, use `$(this).val()` instead of `document.getElementById("txtUserID").value`

example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#txtUserID').bind('keyup', function() {
        var inputValue = $(this).val();
        inputValue = inputValue.replace(/-/g, "");
        // and other replacements here, e.g.
        // inputValue = inputValue.replace(/(^.{7}|.{4})/g, "$1-");
        $(this).val(inputValue);
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/kvAJD/)**

and yep, you forgot `#` before identifier

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/kvAJD/3/)**

Comment: @AgentX44 I think this regex will make your code shorter and clearer: `inputValue = inputValue.replace(/^(.{7})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})/, "$1-$2-$3-$4-$5");` It inserts `-` after 7th, 11th, 15th and 19th char (if I understand what you want). Look the updated demo in my answer!

Comment: I'll try it, but does it work even when the user is just typing?

Comment: I just tried it, when the user is typing the string, the 'auto-dash' only works after typing the 4th character of the last section of the string: 

BEFORE TYPING 4th CHAR: 12345678123412341234123
AFTER: 12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234

Comment: @AgentX44 you're right, let me think a little, because it's even can be another SO question, like _regex to insert dash after 7th char and then after every 4th_

Comment: @AgentX44 I've found this solution: `inputValue = inputValue.replace(/(^.{7}|.{4})/g, "$1-");` it's short, but it still add only one stray `-` when your string length is between 5 and 7

Comment: thanks for this. and I'll do that for the next 3 sets. Thanks a lot. Really appreciate your help ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34038/discussion-between-vladkras-and-agent-x44)

Answer (score 0):

I spot 2 things

You are missing the `#` in your selector `$('#txtUserID')`, and you need to wrap the code in `$(function(){` so it loads on DOM ready:

```
    $(function(){

        $('#txtUserID').bind('input', function () {

              ...

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, you want to fire onChange event. So you need to modify your code look like:

```
$('#txtUserID').bind('change', function () {
    var inputValue =     $(this).val();
    inputValue = inputValue.replace(/-/g, "");
    var outputVal = "";
    var inputLength = inputValue.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputLength; i++) {

        outputVal += inputValue.charAt(i);

        if (i == 7) {
            outputVal += "-";
        }
        if (i == 11) {
            outputVal += "-";
        }
        if (i == 15) {
            outputVal += "-";
        }
        if (i == 19) {
            outputVal += "-";
        }
    }
    $(this).val(outputVal);
});
```

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Rb8BS/

### Update

If you want to fire onInput or paste event, you can change to:

```
$('#txtUserID').bind('change', function () {
    var inputValue =     $(this).val();
    inputValue = inputValue.replace(/-/g, "");
    ...  
    ...
    ...
});
```

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Rb8BS/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use OnInput event...if you want to fire an event on text change

< script type="text/javascript">

```
      function OnInput (event) {
                  var inputValue = document.getElementById("txtUserID").value;

    inputValue = inputValue.replace('/-/g', "");
    var outputVal = "";
    var inputLength = inputValue.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputLength; i++) {

        outputVal += inputValue.charAt(i);

        if (i == 7) {
            outputVal += "-";
        }
        if (i == 11) {
            outputVal += "-";
        }
        if (i == 15) {
            outputVal += "-";
        }
        if (i == 19) {
            outputVal += "-";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("txtUserID").value = outputVal;

    }

    < /script>

    <html>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="txtUserID" oninput="OnInput (event)" value = "@ConsumerID"  tabindex="20" style="width: 250px;" maxLength="36"/>
    </body>
    </html>
```